# IDAPython loading parameters bruteforce

Tags: ida, idapython

I have a binary file for known hardware platform, but nothing more is known.

When I load this file in IDA (with default parameters), nothing good happens - at least does not appear xrefs to readable strings.

I suggest that the case in the loading parameters: the loading address and the entry point. Maybe some even.

The only solution I see in the bruteforce these parameters and re-launch auto analysis. Before that I would like to help IDA by designation some pieces of code - readable strings as strings, small common hardware patterns as code pieces.

Success criteria - the appearance of xrefs to the strings.

Unfortunately I'm newbie in IDAPython, and I'm only has learned to show to IDA strings (by MakeStr-function).

How can I change loading parameters and launch full auto-analysis in IDAPython script?

Comment: Before you go ahead and bruteforce - what do you know about the platform? Do you know the hardware's boot address and such?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm know only platform type - PowerPC and nothing more.

Comment: And is the binary file the full firmware?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'm assuming that it is not full firmware, most likely, this is only part of the changeable firmware.

Comment: Do you have a running version of the software, or only the binary?

Comment: No, I have only the binary file. I understand that conditions are very bad, but but just no way out...

Comment: Do you know if the binary is expected to have a large number of `print` or `debugprint` calls?